# How to loop selectors?

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem making this work. I know there is a solution for this problem, I think I solved it before, but I don't remember how. So..

I have JQuery code

```
$("#button-video").click(function () {
    $("#image").addClass("show");
    $("#image").removeClass("hide");
    $("#video").addClass("hide");
    $("#video").removeClass("show");
    $("#button-gallery").removeClass("active");
    $("#button-video").addClass("active");
});
$("#button-gallery").click(function () {
    $("#video").addClass("show");
    $("#video").removeClass("hide");
    $("#image").addClass("hide");
    $("#image").removeClass("show");
    $("#button-video").removeClass("active");
    $("#button-gallery").addClass("active");
});
```

HTML code

```
<div class="goods-image">
    <a href="" data-lightbox="picture">
        <div class="box" id="image">
            <img src="" alt="product">
            <div class="hover-eye">

            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="box hide" id="video">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?controls=1">
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="image-box">
        <div class="gallery active" id="button-video">
            <p>Galerija</p>
        </div>
        <div class="video" id="button-gallery">
            <p>Video</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are multiple ids like `#button-video_1, #video_1, #image_1, #button-video_2, #video_2, #image_2` and so on. Every one of them does the same thing, but for different picture or video. Because the list is long, how to make this code (above) work for all elements withouth copying and adding a number?

Comment: you could give them all the same CSS class, select using that and bind a click event to it, and then the same code can be executed no matter which element was clicked. You might want to ensure you don't have duplicate IDs, and if you want to find specific elements which are logically associated with a particular instance of the button, then you could use things like siblings, or closest, or find (e.g. within a parent container) to narrow down your search.

Comment: P.S. if you solved it before, you could always go and look at that code to see what you did? You did keep a copy, right?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do things like:

```
$("div[id^='button-video_']").click(function () {
    var id = this.id.replace('button-video_', '');
    $("#image_" + id).addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
    $("#video_" + id).addClass("hide").removeClass("show");
    $("#button-gallery_" + id).removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

$("div[id^='button-gallery_']").click(function () {
    var id = this.id.replace('button-gallery_', '');
    $("#video_" + id).addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
    $("#image_" + id).addClass("hide").removeClass("show");
    $("#button-video_" + id).removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

Using the `[^=...]` to get selectors that start with that string, see :

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

And chaining a couple of them together, e.g.

```
$("#image_" + id).addClass("show").removeClass("hide")
```